# Java - 404 after deploying servlet to Glassfish

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

I'm pretty new to servlets in Java and i was trying to deploy the following servlet with this GET method:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    out.println("<html><body>");
    out.println("<h2>Welcome!</h2>");
    out.println("</body></html>");
}
```

I checked the console and it was deployed successfully, no errors.
However, when i open my browser and go to:

`http://localhost:8080/web1/AddPassenger`

I get the `HTTP Status 404 - Not Found` error.

What could be the problem?

EDIT:
Content of `glassfish-web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>/Web1</context-root>

</glassfish-web-app>
```

Comment: Do you have everything u need in your `web.xml` file?

Comment: The root of the context is incorrect, or there's no mapping to that URL.  How do you deploy this?  In a WAR?  The context root should be the name of the WAR.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the question because i'm new to this, but what's that `web.xml` file?

Comment: I see the `glassfish-web.xml` file and the context root there is set to `Web1`.

Comment: In your project there should be `WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml`...

Comment: Inside the `web.xml` you need to define your `Servlet Mappings`...if you google `web.xml servlet mappings` you should get an idea of how to set it up.

Comment: Also try `Web1` in your url instead of `web1`...some servers are case-sensitive depending on the settings.

Comment: The file that i have is `glassfish-web.xml`, not `web.xml`.
Also, when i try to add the `<servlet-mapping>` tag it gives me an error, like it's invalid syntax.I edited my post with the content of the `xml` file that i have.

Also, i did try `Web1` instead of `web1`, didn't work..

Comment: anybody? :( it's super frustrating

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was the problem, but i installed a new version of Eclipse (Oxygen, i used Mars before that) and it worked!

Many thanks to everyone for their help!